# What happened to the Localized option

Tags: discussion

There used to be a flag or closure reason that the post was too localized, meaning it was very specific to the user or environment. Was that removed? It seems like its still a valid reason to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This changed in June last year [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons)

> **5(A). "Too Localized" is no longer necessary since the specific off-topic reasons now address its main use case. (new)**
>
> Too Localized was, by far, the most misused close reason in our surveys, with both Community Managers and Moderators deeming over 50% of randomly sampled TL closures to not have merited closure (including on SO).
>
> Today, TL is used helpfully on code dump questions on SO, but the new OT reasons are where this is now correctly addressed. SO can use "Large blocks of code with requests for debugging without meaningful supporting info" as a specific OT reason.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with removing it, as it is a valid option. Misuse doesn't mean it has to be removed but trained to be used properly.

Comment: @PirateEric We can still use it in our own community if we want to. We have three different spots for community specific closing, currently (1)commercial 3rd part software, (2) programming question not specific to sharepoint and (3) belong to Serverfault.